# How can i track every error in app.component.ts in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using ionic 2. I want to track every error that occur in ionic 2 `app.component.ts` file .Is there any solution for this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the `code` of your `app.component.ts` file?

Comment: Have you even try to search?

Comment: Sorry i didn't written any code about error handler .It is already developed app.I can't change in every page .is there any option for tracking every error in app.component.ts file only?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler i found this URL but  there is no detailed information

Comment: Yes, You need to do like that.What details do you need?

Comment: But i have to throw error every time ,instead of that i need to capture error information in app.component.ts when it occur any where in app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**IonicErrorHandler**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/IonicErrorHandler/) class for that.This is a global error handler.

> The IonicErrorHandler intercepts the default Console error handling
>   and displays runtime errors as an overlay when using Ionic's Dev Build
>   Server.

*app.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Now if you just do `throw new Error('Im error')` anywhere in your application, you will see your console message.

Here is a great article about it with [**custom error handling**](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/global-error-handling-with-angular2-6b992bdfb59c).

Comment: but we have to throw error every time.instead of that  can we use one code for all pages ?

Comment: No, you must do that.Otherwise, it gets swallowed. I.e. You must rethrow the error otherwise it gets swallowed.